# how to make SQL calls from Serenity?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I trying to fetch data from Db using serenity. I have performed CRUD operations using template formation.
I have used serenity code generation for genrating files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I had the same scenario, and I have found the answers. you can refer this 
**[How to add new chart(any charts, highcharts or d3 charts) in Serenity admin dashboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43516639/how-to-add-new-chartany-charts-highcharts-or-d3-charts-in-serenity-admin-dash/43655513#43655513)**.

Hope this help you :)